# How long do fortresses stay weakened?

Tags: far-cry-4

[image: Fortress on map]

A leader of a fortress has just died and now the Fortress is weakened.

The game seems to really want me to take the Fortress ASAP, but I was wanting to do some other stuff first.

**How long does a Fortress stay "weakened"? Will it ever reach its former glory again?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I know, it stays weakened till you capture it.

Comment: Do you anything (any evidence) to back your claim up?

Comment: @aytimothy not really, but I've never heard from anyone that a Fortress recovered from weakened state.